# Why does C#'s decimal use binary integer significand?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, decimal, 128-bit

The new IEEE 128-bit decimal floating-point type https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal128_floating-point_format specifies that the significand (mantissa) can be represented in one of two ways, either as a simple binary integer, or in densely packed decimal (in which case every ten bits represent three decimal digits).

C#'s `decimal` type predates this standard, but has the same idea. It went with binary integer significand.

On the face of it, this seems inefficient; for addition and subtraction, to line up the significands, you have to divide one of them by a power of ten; and division is the most expensive of all the arithmetic operators.

What was the reason for the choice? What corresponding advantage was considered worth that penalty?

Comment: "because that's what got written"? .NET 1 shipped in early 2002; there may have been specific technical r for the choice, or it may have been entirely "what meets the intended behavior and we can ship on schedule?" - but: it might be ambitious to hope to find the full reasons at this point

Comment: Because that is what Intel uses in the  floating point unit in the microprocessor.  See : https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library.html

Comment: @jdweng That link discusses a software floating-point library. I don't see anything in it that suggests decimal floating-point is implemented in hardware on Intel CPUs today, let alone when C# was invented?

Comment: Where to you think Intel uses the library?  See : https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/case-studies/floating-point-case-study.pdf

Comment: @jdweng floating point units on the Intel processors are binary rather than decimal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Choosing one representation is almost always about trade offs.

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_integer_decimal)

> A binary encoding is inherently less efficient for conversions to or
> from decimal-encoded data, such as strings (ASCII, Unicode, etc.) and
> BCD. A binary encoding is therefore best chosen only when the data are
> binary rather than decimal. IBM has published some unverified
> performance data.

[Here](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decperf.html) you can find more about the relative performance.

Basically, it asserts your thoughts, that decimal significant is generally faster, but most operations show similar performance and binary even winning in division. Also keep in mind, since Intel mostly seems to rely on binary significants (i couldn't find hints about other manufactures), they are more likely to get hardware support and than might beat decimals by a good margin.